# How to check if all values in bool array are true?

Tags: c, arrays, boolean

In **C**,
what is the best and simplest way to check if all values in a bool table are true?
I tried something like this but it doesn't work

```
for(i = 0; i < value; i++){
            if(bool_table[i] == 0)
                table_true = 0;
            else
                table_true = 1;
    }
```

The problem with this code is that sometimes if the first value is true then it will set `table_true = 1`

Comment: "then it will set `table_true = 1`" How can that be? And I would write `if (bool_table[i] == 0) { table_true = 0; break; }`, just for efficiency's sake.

Comment: How do you initialize your `table_true` variable? Make sure to give an initial value, otherwise you'll end up with an uninitailized value.

Comment: Before the loop, add `table_true = 1;`, but to be more efficient instead of a conditional you could have `table_true &= bool_table[i]` in the loop.

Comment: Also, you might as well `break` from the loop as soon as you find a `false` element, as checking subsequent elements cannot change the result.

Comment: Oh dear.  Your edit just made it worse.  Previous comments were predicated on the original version of your question, which was a better start.  What you have now will always give you the value of `bool_table[value - 1]`.

Comment: I already set 'table_true = 1;'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the following loop goes through the entire array without finding a `false` entry, then at the end of the loop `i` will equal `value`

```
for(i = 0; i < value; i++)
    if ( !bool_table[i] )
        break;

table_true = (i == value);
```

Comment: `int table[3] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
   int n,t = 0;
   for(n = 0; n < 3; n++){
        if(!table[n])
            break;
        else t = (n == 3);
   }
    printf("%d",t);`

Comment: @WhizzMirray Note that `n==3` will never be true inside the loop.

Comment: This code would be easier to understand if `value` were renamed to `book_table_len`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
table_true = 1;
for(i = 0; i < value; i++)
        if (!bool_table[i]) {
            table_true = 0;
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how one evaluates "best" or "simplest." Does "best" mean fastest? Or least lines of code? And simplest, is that most simple for a beginner? Or for a group of developers that eat and sleep C and use pointers regularly?

Here's my somewhat unconventional approach:

```
bool *each = bool_table; // pointer to first element
bool *end = each + value; // stop condition
while (*each && each != end) {
    each++;
}
return each != end;
```

Comment: Based on the [WTF per line ratio](http://www.osnews.com/story/19266/WTFs_m), I suggest you to not use that algorithm in serious software. Although it does the trick, it's a bit obtuse and harder to understand than it could be.